# react native redux toolkit devtools

Tags: react-native, redux, expo, redux-toolkit, redux-devtools

how can I add redux devtools with redux toolkit ?

```
import { configureStore, getDefaultMiddleware, compose } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';
import reducers from './reducers';
import createSagaMiddleware from 'redux-saga';
import saga from './saga';

const sagaMiddleware = createSagaMiddleware();

const store = configureStore({
  reducer: reducers,
  devTools: process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production',

  middleware: getDefaultMiddleware => getDefaultMiddleware({ thunk: false }).concat(sagaMiddleware)
});
sagaMiddleware.run(saga);

export default store;
```

..................................................

Answer (score 1):

It's activated by default with configureStore() and you can access it with this tool. [react-native-debugger](https://github.com/jhen0409/react-native-debugger/blob/master/docs/getting-started.md)

Answer (score 0):

As the official documentation specify in the **Simplifying Store Setup with configureStore**​ section: https://redux-toolkit.js.org/usage/usage-guide#simplifying-store-setup-with-configurestore, you don't have to add anything else since it already does it for you.